# PHP String Manipulation printing function onclick adding "

Tags: php, html

HTML

```
<button class="btn btn-danger" onclick="loadPlayer('28JVGV92L'," 0)="">RepeaterCreeper</button>
```

PHP

```
echo "<button class='btn btn-danger' onclick=loadPlayer('{$caller['playerTag']}', {$i})>" . $caller['username'] . "</button>";
```

I have no clue why the output given is `loadPlayer('28JVGV92L', " 0)=""` what I was expecting the output to be was `loadPlayer('28JVGV92L', 0)` as there is 2 parameter for the function loadPlayer. I'm apparently not understanding how PHP manages strings and why it adds `"` whenever I don't even say to add it.

If you guys could reference me to a place where I could learn whatever topic this is called that'd be helpful. I've looked into PHP String Manipulation but I really just don't know why it's adding `"` and the extra `=""` to the echoed statement.

Comment: `echo $i;` I suspect.

Comment: @AbraCadaver What's wrong with it?

Comment: post the rest of the code, maybe on 3v4l and post a link to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your quotes are off, causing the browser to think $i is intended to be an attribute of the button, and adds the `=""`. The only way that makes sense is if there is a quote in the value of `$i`. be careful how you define your variables.

Comment: Oh I see... let me change the code to `echo "<button class='btn btn-danger' onclick=\"loadPlayer('{$caller['playerTag']}', {$i})\">" . $caller['username'] . "</button>";`

Comment: awesome, if this was the solution please hit the check mark :)